# Replace default featured image with custom field

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-featured-image

what i need is to replace the (assign the) featured image with my custom field value of my custom post type..
Is it possible..

I am holding images on another host which inserted the url of the thumbnail of the custom post as a custom field.
I am using external table for all this data

I tried to write a plugin for some filters to achive this but..
add_filter(‘post_thumbnail_html’…. etc

Didnt work well. Because either

a- Since some templates check if the post has thumbnail i guess this filter fails because i am using a custom post type without a thumbnail image
b- wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, ‘post-thumbnail’ ); was used which had no available hooks to replace the src.

I also tried image resize hook which i couldnt manage either..

Is there a way to make it match like featured_image => my_custom_image_url_field

Or any other ideas how this can be achieved..

Answer (score 0):

You can set featured image automatically on post save/update with your custom field data